# WebScraper and Json format

Tags: json, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm trying to make a simple nodeJS webscraper and I can not figure out how to format my result in Json file.

I'm using express, request, cheerio and fs.

This is my code :

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var app     = express();
var url = 'http://www.footmercato.net/';

  request(url, function(err, resp, body) {
      if (!err) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        var json = { title : "", article : "", date : "" };

        var article = $('.text p');
        var articleTxt = article.text();
        json.article = articleTxt;
  }

  JSON.stringify(json);

  })

  app.listen('8080');
```

When I launch this program nothing happend, it was working before the   `JSON.stringify(json);`

Does anyone know how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the stringify function inside the callback then write the string to a file.  if the function is outside the callback the javascript object you want to convert hasn't been made yet

Also on a sidenote a javascript object is not JSON.  I've changed the definitions below.

```
request(url, function(err, resp, body) {
 if (!err) {
   var $ = cheerio.load(body);
   var jsObject = { title : "", article : "", date : "" };
   var article = $('.text p');
   var articleTxt = article.text();
   jsObject.article = articleTxt;
   var json = JSON.stringify(jsObject);
   fs.writeFileSync('path/to/file', json);

 }
```

Comment: thanks a lot Peter for your answer. When I run the program I've this error, do you know what I've to do ?  return binding.writeString(fd, buffer, offset, length, position);
                 ^

TypeError: First argument must be file descriptor
    at TypeError (native)
    at Object.fs.writeSync (fs.js:792:18)
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\leona\Desktop\school_projects\Scraper\server.js:16:9)
    at Request.self.callback

Comment: @MalkovitchJohn   sorry I mean't to write fs.writeFileSync, updated code

Comment: Thanks Peter, I've changed it by  fs.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify(json, null, 4), function(err) {
           console.log('File successfully written! - Check your project directory for the output.json file');
       }) and now it's working.